# Manage and clear activity backstack

Tags: android, launchmode

I have a dashboard activity from where i can move to some activity flow as below -

```
1) A(DashboardActivity)> B > C > D
2) A(DashboardActivity)> E > F
3) A(DashboardActivity)> G > H > I
```

Suppose i have accessed the application in such a way that now i am on activity D as below (using step 1)- 
`A > B > C > D` (current activity task stack)
now i want to launch to activity F(step 2 activity) in such a way that
on back, it come to E and then A and will come out from application. on Pressing back user should see this flow of activity -

```
F > E > A > Out from the application`
```

I don't want to go again on trace of activity D. How can i achieve this in application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [TaskStackBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html).This will help you to create back stack.

In Activity D use this code to launch Activity F

```
    TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
            .addParentStack(AActivity.class)
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, AActivity.class))
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, EActivity.class))
            .addNextIntent(new Intent(this, FActivity.class))
            .startActivities();
```

To use `TaskStackBuilder` you min sdk version should be 16 or higher.

For sdk less than 16 you can manually check in `onBackPressed` and start Activity.

**In Activity F:**

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed(){
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

     if (extras.containsKey("FROM_ACTIVITY_D_FOR_STACK")){
        // start Activity E
     }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
     }

  }
```

Do this for other activities where you want to add back stack